# How to create database of images using C programming?

Tags: c++, c, database, linux, image-processing

I need to create a simple database using C programming to store images. Then how I can use the database to feed images one by one to another application. Each image has one ID. If any of the image matches with my application need. Its corresponding ID must be print as output.

I need to create database for around 350 images. My main application has been written in C. So can any one help me how to create database and how to link it with the main application?

Comment: I can't quite follow what you are asking here; do you want to know what databases are out there that you can use? SQLite has a nice C API, but I think this question is far too broad as it is.

Comment: This link might help you [Reading & Saving images from a database using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dbeniwal321/reading-and-saving-images-fromto-a-database-using-C-Sharp/)

Comment: You could perhaps just use [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be to store as BLOBs in [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) db which integrates as a single .c file in your project. See example C file that demonstrates two different ways of accessing blobs. One using bind and one using blob api.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

sqlite3 *db;

int error(char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", msg);
    if(db)
        sqlite3_close(db);
    exit(1);
}

int gettype(char **imgtype, int columns, char **colval, char **colname) {
    int col;

    if(columns!=1)
        return 1;

    snprintf((char *)imgtype, 4, "%s", colval[0]);

    return 0;
}

int getrowid(sqlite3_int64 *rowid, int columns, char **colval, char **colname) {
    int col;

    if(columns!=1)
        return 1;

    *rowid=(int)strtol(colval[0], NULL, 10);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    enum { PROG, FUNC, TABLE, NAME };

    sqlite3_blob *dblob;
    char sqlcmd[1024];
    sqlite3_int64 rowid=0;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *zErrMsg=0;

    char filename[1024];
    char outname[1024];
    char imgtype[4];
    FILE *fblob;
    char *blobmem;
    long blobsize;


    if(argc!=4) 
        error("usage: blob <get|put> <table> <filename>");


    if(sqlite3_open(DATABASE, &db)) 
        error((char*)sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    sqlite3_busy_timeout(db, TIMEOUT);


    // using bind api
    if(strcmp(argv[FUNC], "put")==0) {
        snprintf(filename, 1024, "%s", basename(argv[NAME]));
        strtok(filename, ".");
        snprintf(imgtype, 4, "%s", strtok(NULL, "."));

        if(!strlen(imgtype) || !(strcasecmp(imgtype, "gif")==0 || strcasecmp(imgtype, "jpg")==0 || strcasecmp(imgtype, "png")==0))
            error("wrong extension / img type");

        fblob=fopen(argv[NAME], "r");
        if(fblob==NULL) 
            error("file not found");

        fseek(fblob, 0L, SEEK_END);
        blobsize=ftell(fblob);
        if(!blobsize) 
            error("wrong file size");

        blobmem=malloc(blobsize);
        if(!blobmem) 
            error("unable to allocate memory");

        rewind(fblob);
        if(fread(blobmem, blobsize, 1, fblob)!=1) 
            error("unable to read file");
        fclose(fblob);

        snprintf(sqlcmd, 1024, "delete from '%s' where name like '%s';", argv[TABLE], filename);
        if(sqlite3_exec(db, sqlcmd, NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg)!=SQLITE_OK) 
            error(zErrMsg);

        snprintf(sqlcmd, 1024,  "insert into '%s'(name, type, data) values(?, ?, ?);", argv[TABLE]);
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlcmd, -1, &stmt, 0)!=SQLITE_OK) 
            error((char*)sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, filename, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, imgtype, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
        sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 3, blobmem, blobsize, SQLITE_STATIC);

        if(sqlite3_step(stmt)!=SQLITE_DONE) 
            error((char*)sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        if(sqlite3_finalize(stmt)!=SQLITE_OK) 
            error((char*)sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        free(blobmem);

    }
    // using blob api
    else if(strcmp(argv[FUNC], "get")==0) {
        snprintf(filename, 1024, "%s", argv[NAME]);
        strtok(filename, ".");

        snprintf(sqlcmd, 1024, "select rowid from '%s' where name like '%s';", argv[TABLE], filename);
        if(sqlite3_exec(db, sqlcmd, (void *)&getrowid, &rowid, &zErrMsg)!=SQLITE_OK) 
            error(zErrMsg);

        if(!rowid) 
            error("not found");

        snprintf(sqlcmd, 1024, "select type from '%s' where name like '%s';", argv[TABLE], filename);
        if(sqlite3_exec(db, sqlcmd, (void *)&gettype, &imgtype, &zErrMsg)!=SQLITE_OK)
            error(zErrMsg);

        if(!strlen(imgtype) || !(strcasecmp(imgtype, "gif")==0 || strcasecmp(imgtype, "jpg")==0 || strcasecmp(imgtype, "png")==0))
            error("wrong extension / img type");

        if(sqlite3_blob_open(db, "main", argv[TABLE], "data", rowid, 0, &dblob)!=SQLITE_OK) 
            error((char*)sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        blobsize=sqlite3_blob_bytes(dblob);
        if(!blobsize)
            error("image is 0 bytes in size");

        blobmem=malloc(blobsize);
        if(!blobmem)
            error("unable to allocate memory");

        if(sqlite3_blob_read(dblob, blobmem, blobsize, 0)!=SQLITE_OK)
            error("unable to read image");

        sqlite3_blob_close(dblob);

        snprintf(outname, 1024, "%s.%s", filename, imgtype);
        fblob=fopen(outname, "w");
        if(fblob==NULL)
            error("unable to open target file");

        if(fwrite(blobmem, blobsize, 1, fblob)!=1)
            error("unable to write to target file");

        fclose(fblob);
        free(blobmem);
    }
    else 
        error("wrong usage");

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

In order to store ID with the image just create another column in the same table.